# ¿Existe un evento en angular 2+ que me permita saber si se esta abandonando un componente?

Tags: typescript, angular5

Tengo la siguiente vista: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Quiero implementar una forma de que si intento abandonar ese componente, me pregunte primero si quiero hacerlo. Estuve leyendo los ciclos de vida de un componente en angular, probé el ngOndestroy() pero no se ejecuta al cambiar de componentes. Estoy usando angular material.

Comment: podrias usar algo de JS

Comment: toda ventana modal de Bootstrap si es el caso posee eventos como show y hide donde deberias controlar el hide

Comment: Te refieres a detectar un cambio en la URL?

Answer (score 0):

Si es tu caso con bootstrap, podrias usar algo de JS:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PDle/QlgIONtM1aqA2Qemk5gPOE7wFq8+Em+G/hmo5Iq0CCmYZLv3fVRDJ4MMwEA" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-7aThvCh9TypR7fIc2HV4O/nFMVCBwyIUKL8XCtKE+8xgCgl/PQGuFsvShjr74PBp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
$('#exampleModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    alert('Saliendo de la modal ..!!');
})
</script>
```

Si te fijas uso el evento hide que es llamado al momento de intentar salir de una modal, podrias agregar una confirmacion para salir de la misma.

Espero te sirva como guia..!!